# how to make dots little bigger in the slideshow of forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on making slideshow of forms and it is working fine. As you can see if I click those dots, it will open another form. I have change the transition from top to bottom after I click the dots and here is my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GErJzQ).

In my above codepen link, somehow my dots became very small. Check my original [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwWZpV). In this my dots are big and properly spaced as well. I want to make my dots something like that. What is wrong in my fist codepen link and how can I make dots bigger.

Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
   <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
               <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
         <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
         <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>  
  <div class="container">
   <h3>INSURANCE FORM</h3>
   <h4><i>BASIC DETAILS</i></h4>
   <br>    
    <div id="slides" class="container-fluid" >
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>FIRST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 1">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>LAST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>EMAIL</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>COUNTRY</label>
                  <select name="country" class="form-control">
                     <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>PROVINCE</label>
                  <select name="province" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>CITY</label>
                  <select name="city" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>FIRST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>LAST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>EMAIL</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>COUNTRY</label>
                  <select name="country" class="form-control">
                     <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>PROVINCE</label>
                  <select name="province" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>CITY</label>
                  <select name="city" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>FIRST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>LAST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>EMAIL</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>COUNTRY</label>
                  <select name="country" class="form-control">
                     <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>PROVINCE</label>
                  <select name="province" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>CITY</label>
                  <select name="city" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>FIRST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>LAST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>EMAIL</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>COUNTRY</label>
                  <select name="country" class="form-control">
                     <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>PROVINCE</label>
                  <select name="province" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>CITY</label>
                  <select name="city" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>FIRST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>LAST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>EMAIL</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>COUNTRY</label>
                  <select name="country" class="form-control">
                     <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>PROVINCE</label>
                  <select name="province" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>CITY</label>
                  <select name="city" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>FIRST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>LAST NAME</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>EMAIL</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>COUNTRY</label>
                  <select name="country" class="form-control">
                     <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>PROVINCE</label>
                  <select name="province" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>CITY</label>
                  <select name="city" class="form-control">
                     <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>  
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using background images on the `a` tags in the first codepen but default list bullets in the second codepen (but changing color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `<li>`'s bullet points, you can edit it changing the `font-size`, try :

```
.slick-dots li {font-size:22px;}
```

---

Since you also need to be able to edit the space inbetween each bullet and make each of them look empty you can use :

```
.slick-dots li {
    font-size:22px;
    margin: -5px 0px;
    list-style-type:circle;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active {
    color: black;
    list-style-type: initial;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works.. Also is there any way to control the spaces between those bullet points? And how can I make bullet points with whole in it, just like I have in my original code pen link.

Comment: awesome.. also do you know I can make bullet with whole in it ( maybe using wrong word) just like I have in my actual codepen..

Comment: @shortcut of course, try to learn CSS by yourself it is really not complicated :) Here's a site with everything you need : https://www.w3schools.com/css/ and learn about the inspect element tool which will make it butter easy.

Comment: sorry I just keep asking question.. after I added list-type circle as you suggested.. when I click those dots, it doesn't show which dot is selected.. in my earlier codepen it used to tell me I am on this form.. I want to use orange color for that dot if I select that form..

Comment: @shortcut we've all been there don't worry, I added a fix so you can see the active bullets as full.

Answer (score 0):

[image]this will help you to change the size of the bullets:

```
<style>
li{list-style-type:none;}
li:before{content:'\00b7'; font-size:30px; line-height:24px; vertical-align:middle;}
</style>
```

If my answer helps you, please vote+1 my answer!

Comment: I tried this but somehow it works weird. First of all it shows square bullet points. Second if I click those bullet, it doesn't work properly. You can try this out in the codepen link. I was using font size as 100 px.

Comment: Do it like me and it will work, check the image that I uploaded. You do not do something that is why it does not work, I put your code and added style tags as you can see and it works perfectly. Vote+ if I helped you.